# Нужно заменить строчку в скрипте Linux

Tags: linux, bash

У меня в скрипте выскакивает синтаксическая ошибка. Вот сообщение:

> REPLACE + '*': синтаксическая ошибка: ожидается операнд (неверный маркер «'*'»)

Вот часть кода где есть ошибка, подскажите как можно исправить:

```
REPLACE=$[REPLACE + '*']
done
RESULT=${str//s/$REPLACE}
```

Comment: первая строчка это что вы хотели этим добиться? отличный гайд по массивам - http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays?s[]=array

Answer (score 1):

Как-то странно вы присваиваете значение переменной. ИМХО должно быть так (для примера):

```
REPLACE=template
REPLACE=$REPLACE'*'
echo $REPLACE
# template*
str=str
echo ${str/s/$REPLACE}
# template*tr
```